# Generate declaration file programmatically

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I know I can run `tsc --declaration myfile.ts` to generate a declaration file. Is there some way I can do this programmatically with the TS compiler?

i.e something like

```
const ts = require('typescript');
const out = ts.declarations('source-string');
```

Comment: I don't think there's a one-liner.  The general idea would be to start with an example compiler like [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-minimal-compiler), enable the `declaration` and `emitDeclarationOnly` compiler options, and pass a custom `CompilerHost` whose `getSourceFile` method returns your source code and whose `writeFile` method captures the declarations.  I don't have the interest to put together a full working sample, but maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this github project, can be solution for you:
https://github.com/SitePen/dts-generator

Start: npm install dts-generator

Generate your d.ts bundle programmatically:

```
require('dts-generator').default({
    name: 'package-name',
    project: '/path/to/package-directory',
    out: 'package-name.d.ts'
});
```

For more info you should visit link above :).